# Terrfaform - AWS_AMI data source doesn't return any result

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Update: Found out about owners. `Valid values: an AWS account ID, self (the current account), or an AWS owner alias (e.g. amazon, aws-marketplace, microsoft).` But I still don't get any result.

```
data "aws_ami" "example" {
  owners = ["microsoft"]

  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Base"]
  }
}
```

`Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.`

Also how does one know directory structure for a image from ec2 console? Like for example, in this [article](https://letslearndevops.com/2018/08/23/terraform-get-latest-centos-ami/) they're using a directory structure. How would I know the directory structure of a image in ec2 console? I could filter using name, but wanted to know how to figure out the directory structure as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to `EC2->AMI` and select `Public Images`. Then search for AMI of interest. For example, `ami-0885b1f6bd170450c` (ubuntu 20.04) in `us-east-1`:

[image]

For Windows, the owner is differnt:

[image]

Comment: Seems like I still don't get a result for windows. Here is a screenshot, https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgQIp.png

Comment: @JohnDoe Maybe its not available in your region?. I have it in us-east-1 as you can see on my screenshot.

Comment: You're right. I can see the image in EU-WEST-2. Though I can see the image when launching  ec2 insance in `ap-south-1` but it isn't visible in AMI panel. Any difference there?

Comment: If you see it in when instance launching, get its `AMI Id`, and search using it, instead of Ami Name.